# What's the difference between this.bla to Object.prototype.bla

Tags: javascript, function, this, prototype

Let's say I have this code:

```
(function(global) {
    function Bar(foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
        return this;
    }

    Bar.prototype.getFoo = function() {
        return this.foo;
    };

    Bar.prototype.setFoo = function(val) {
        return (this.foo = val);
    };
})(this);
```

What is the difference between creating functions like `setFoo` with `prototype` and just doing it like this:

```
function Bar(foo) {
    this.getFoo = function() {
        return this.foo;
    };
}
```

I know what prototype is and what it means, I just can't figure out, why some people assign functions with prototype, because if I assign them with this, they will be available also every time I create a new instance of Bar.

Comment: Your way you create seperate function per instance of `Bar`. Prototype way it creates only one function for **all** instances. It saves memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The quick answer = function sharing + smaller memory footprint

When you're using `prototype.functionName` all instances **share the same function** (only one copy in memory), but if you use `this.functionName` in your constructor each instance has **its own copy of the same function** (exists multiple times in memory).

Using `prototype` has two implications:

1. Memory footprint - as mentioned
2. Subsequent function change on the prototype is reflected on all existing (and future of course) instances - there are rare occasions when one would like to do this, but it's there any it can be used

### Advanced - you can have both

You can also have both in which case the *local* copy has precedence over the prototype which means that you could do stuff like this:

```
function Crazy(name)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.callMe = function() {
        return "Where are you " + this.name;
    };
}

Crazy.prototype.callMe = function() {
    return this.name + " come here";
};

var inst = new Crazy("Robert");
inst.callMe(); // "Where are you Robert"
delete inst.callMe;
inst.callMe(); // "Robert come here"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `prototype`, the function is **shared**, when you assign the function to `this`, they are not. Instead, every instance will have its *own* **copy** of the funciton.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one instance of the "class" (using the term loosely), they all share the same prototype. So attaching things there is more light-weight, and it guarantees that they all have the same version (if that is what you want).

Think about it as instance fields vs class fields.

Prototypes can also be chained to allow for "inheritance" of fields.

Answer (score 0):

An aside :

With prototypal inheritance, there's a fundamentel difference between own properties and inherited ones.

Sometimes this can be quite relevant.

A classic for loop that is often used, only checks for the 'own properties', taking this form :

```
for (prop in array) {
if (array.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      dostuff
}
```

When assigning to `this`, alle properties are own properties, making the hasOwnProperty check irrelevant.